# reading FIT files in Mathematica

Tags: import

Has anybody been able to parse FIT files in Mathematica? The format was developed by Garmin and is used to store data from GPS devices and workout equipment. Details can be found at https://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit/

There is a Python package that can parse these (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fitparse/1.0.0) but it hasn't been updated in years and I haven't been able to get it to work.

--

Update -- I got fitparse working.

[image]

Comment: There also seems to be an [R implementation here](https://github.com/kuperov/fit). Since you can automatically install a copy of R from within *Mathematica* and call R functions, perhaps that might be useful here. Alternatively, `GPSBabel` seems able to convert FIT to GPX, and *Mathematica* [can read GPX natively](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GPX.html).

Comment: GPSBabel seems to toss everything except time stamp, coordinates, and altitude. Mathematica, in its import, then tosses the altitude. I'll try the R solution and continue to work with the Python package as time allows.

Comment: Thanks for the checking! If you come up with a workable method, please consider posting it as a self-answer. I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: I got fitparse working in Python. The trick is not to try running Python 2.7 code in Python 3.5. I'll improve this all later, but my initial Python and Mathematica code can be found at https://github.com/MichaelSternNYC/fit2Mathematica

Comment: Michael, that's great to hear! Would you post your last comment as a self-answer, so your question will show up as answered for future searchers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After experimenting with the free multiplatform tool GPSBabel (http://www.gpsbabel.org/) and with the Python module Fitparse (https://github.com/dtcooper/python-fitparse), I can share the following:

1. If you want latitude and longitude *only*, GPSBabel is fine. It converts the spatial coordinates in a Fit file into GPX format, which Mathematica can import. Unfortunately, it doesn't bring over anything except time stamp, location and elevation, and Mathematica then tosses the elevation data. This was not adequate for my purposes, but for some people it may suffice.
2. Fitparse worked much better. It requires Python 2.7. I wrote a python script that uses Fitparse to convert a specified Fit file into a text file containing a nested list of Mathematica `Association`s, which can then be imported into Mathematica. Using Pythonica you might be able to do the conversion directly, without saving the converted data to disk and importing it, but the save-to-disk-and-import method is no great hassle.

FIT is a flexible format that will contain different fields depending on what is being measured and by what kind of device. My conversion preserves everything in the original file -- latitude, longitude, elevation, heart rate, cadence, temperature, whatever. My tool stores this in a nested list of Associations, where the outer Association specifies the time stamp and the type of record, while the inner list of associations specifies the data associated with that time stamp and record (heart rate, cadence, etc.), and the unit for each one.

You can see my python code for doing the conversion and sample Mathematica code that uses the output, along with a sample FIT file, at [github.com/MichaelSternNYC/fit2Mathematica](http://github.com/MichaelSternNYC/fit2Mathematica).